# how i can connect nox with vscode or android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, emulation

please check my error

```
PS C:\Users\Masoud\Desktop\New\myapp> flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G965N in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             62.3s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...                 7.1s
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
could not read ok from ADB Server
* failed to start daemon
adb.exe: cannot connect to daemon
Command: C:\Users\Masoud\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 127.0.0.1:62001 
shell am start -a android.intent.action.RUN -f 0x20000000 --ez
enable-background-compilation true --ez enable-dart-profiling true
--ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points
true com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity
```

vs code or android studio create apk in my emulator and disconnected.

my flutter doctor is ok

and this my connection

```
C:\Program Files\Nox\bin>nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001
adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
* daemon started successfully *
connected to 127.0.0.1:62001
```